# Execute Javascript command just before form is sent - after validation success

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have an HTML form, with some fields that have simple HTML validation (such as `required` attribute).

How can I execute an arbitrary Javascript command, after validation has passed, just before the form is submitted to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    // whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how you could do it with jQuery

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  valid = validate();
  if (!valid) {
    // you stop the form from submitting 
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```